# WP child theme weirdness

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Okay, SO I have made a very basic child theme for just a few theme tweaks.  The trouble is when I replace one of the woocommerce templates it causes completely unexpected HTML to be rendered.  Can anyone show me where I am going wrong?

Original template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Price, including microdata for SEO
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product;
?>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>

    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />

</div>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <p class="price"><span class="amount">&#36;1.60</span>&ndash;<span class="amount">&#36;25.00</span></p>

    <meta itemprop="price" content="1.6" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />

</div>
```

Child template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Price, including microdata for SEO
 *
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product;
?>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

<?php if (is_product() and $post->post_name == 'club-high-fear'): ?>

      <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per month</p>

<?php elseif (is_product() and $post->post_name == 'club-medium-fear'): ?>

      <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per month</p>

<?php elseif (is_product() and $post->post_name == 'club-low-fear'): ?>

      <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per month</p>

<?php elseif (is_product() and $post->post_name == 'self-study-online-course'): ?>

      <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per course</p>

<?php elseif (is_product() and $post->post_name == '10-week-workshop'): ?>

      <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per workshop</p>

<?php elseif (is_product() and $post->post_name == 'coaching'): ?>

      <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per minute or $25 per email</p>

<?php else: ?>
       <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

    <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); ?>" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/<?php echo $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock'; ?>" />

</div>
```

And child template's rendered HTML:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

    <p class="price"><span class="amount">&#36;1.60</span>&ndash;<span class="amount">&#36;25.00</span></p>
              <p class="price"><span class="amount">&#36;1.60</span>&ndash;<span class="amount">&#36;25.00</span> per minute or $25 per email</span>


    <meta itemprop="price" content="1.6" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />

</div>
```

I dont understand why the price is being outputted twice or why the meta tags are getting pulled inside the p tag that doesnt even close, any insights would be much appreciated.  Also one of my first questions here so school me if I did anything wrong.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the `$poduct` object, i.e. `$product->get_price_html();`. Did you change anything in there?

Comment: I havent no, that method is still returning the correct output and is used in both the working example and the non working example.  What do you think could be going on with the object?

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong with the object... you could try filtering the output with `add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'function_name' );`

Comment: That is where I went, cant seem to get that to work right either.
    function append_text_to_price( $price, $product ) {

 if ($product->get_title() == 'coaching'): {
  return $price . " per minute or $25 per email";
 }
}

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'append_text_to_price', 100, 2 );

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, haven't used woocommerce, but isn't there body classes applied to specific pages that causes the unexpected output? Had an issue with that on a theme I had to tweak.

Answer (score 0):

In each if statement try replace `and` with `&&` so

```
<?php if (is_product() and $post->post_name == 'club-high-fear'): ?>
```

would become

```
<?php if (is_product() && $post->post_name == 'club-high-fear'): ?>
```

Also try wrapping the contents of the if statements in curly brackets.

```
<?php if (is_product() and $post->post_name == 'club-high-fear') { ?>

  <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per month</p>

<?php } ....?>
```

You can make that code a bit shorter by using the  `||` or sign.

```
<?php if (is_product()  && $post->post_name == 'club-high-fear' || $post->post_name == 'club-medium-fear' ||  $post->post_name == 'club-low-fear'){ ?>

  <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per month</p>

<?php } elseif (is_product() && $post->post_name == 'self-study-online-course'){ ?>

  <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per course</p>

<?php } elseif (is_product() && $post->post_name == '10-week-workshop'){ ?>

  <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per workshop</p>

<?php } elseif (is_product() && $post->post_name == 'coaching') { ?>

  <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> per minute or $25 per email</p>

<?php } else { ?>
   <p class="price"> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Tried both, same result.  I had wondered if it was a simple syntax issue, but I cant see it so far.

Comment: From your output it seems that the `else` is being printed out first and then the last `else if` is being printed. What you posted above is what you have in your template file?

Comment: Yep, I thought that too, but even if it did that the syntax it is outputting is wrong.  Even worse now, if I put the original template file in my child theme directory it still outputs the same wrong stuff, if I rename it the output returns to default.  I have done a couple jobs for this client that make me feel like there is a cache somewhere I dont know about....but it just doesnt make sense.